# Use swagger-codegen in maven and split model into more package

Tags: swagger-codegen, swagger-codegen-maven-plugin

I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to use swagger-codegen and split model into more packages? Like:

   - com.petstore.model.goods
   - com.petstore.model.customers
   - com.petstore.model.invoices
2. If this is not possible, which tool do you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use customized templates (CLI option: `-t`) to archive a different package name for each model. You will need to move the auto-generated models to a different folders conforming the new package name though.